# How to target siblings / children of complex component in Material UI/JSS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm using Material UI currently in my project. It's working well, but one thing that I can't figure out is how to style child and sibling components using JSS.

For example, Material UI's  component renders out to something like this:

```html
<div class="MuiFormControl-root-36 MuiFormControl-marginNormal-37">
   <label class="MuiFormLabel-root-45 MuiInputLabel-root-40 MuiInputLabel-formControl-41 MuiInputLabel-animated-44 MuiInputLabel-shrink-43" data-shrink="true">Field label</label>
   <div class="MuiInput-root-52 MuiInput- 
        formControl-53"><input aria-invalid="false" class="MuiInput-input-60" 
        name="fieldname" type="text" value=""></div>
</div>
```

From the [Material UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) I know that  is just a wrapper for some of the lower level components. I can target these individual components using `createMuiTheme()` like this:

```javascript
MuiInput: {
        formControl: {
            'label + &': {
                marginTop: '30px'
            }
        },
        root: {
            '&$focused': {
                boxShadow: '0px 3px 8px rgba(108, 108, 108, 0.16)'
            },
            borderRadius: '40px',
            padding: '7px 16px',
            background: 'white',
            transition: 'box-shadow 0.2s',
        }
    }
```

What I don't understand is how to target children and/or siblings in these components - for example, in my `createMuiTheme` function, how can I target the MuiFormLabel component that is inside the MuiFormControl component? Or, how can I target the MuiInput component if the MuiFormLabel component has a certain class? I know I can target the *element* using normal CSS (e.g. '& label') but I don't know how to target the component/class since the class names are dynamic.

Comment: Could you provide a full example in https://codesandbox.io/s/new or the like ?

Answer (score 0):

You can style the MuiFormLabel component directly, why would you need to style it over MuiFormControl?

Comment: But what about targeting siblings? I know that I can use '&' to target the current element and I can use normal CSS selectors to target elements directly, how since the class names are generated automatically I don't know how to actually target specific components. Is this possible?

Comment: @AndrewKilham You use the same syntax, just referencing the "original" name (like `&:hover:not($button)`). See my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55067108/200987 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/54057130/200987

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each component in its own `withStyles` HOC and style them directly. Keeping the styles at the component level rather than trying to style the nested components from their parent.

```js
const styles = createStyles({
    root: {
        padding: 0
    },
    childRoot: {
        color: 'red'
    }
});

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        
        return (
            <ul className={classes.root}>
                <fooComponent>
                    Bar
                </fooComponent>
            </ul>
        );    
    }
}

const fooComponent = withStyles(styles)((props) => {

    return (
        <li className={classes.childRoot}>
            { props.children }
        </li>
    );
});

export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

**Update:**

Alternatively if you want to use multiple components in the same file you can wrap them in their own HOC.

```js
const renderFoo = withStyles(styles)((props) => {
  const { bar, classes } = props;
  
  return (
    <div classNames={classes[bar]}>
      Baz
    </div>
  )

}

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <renderFoo variant='bar' />
    </div>
}

export default MyComponent
```