# Can't override a style of a deeply nested component (Material-UI Jss Styling)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

Material-UI's ExpansionPanelSummary component allows to render an icon inside it via the `expandIcon` prop, and to change its style by the `expandIcon` css class.
As you can see in the [implementation of the component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ExpansionPanelSummary/ExpansionPanelSummary.js#L66), this class has nested class which adds transform:

```
'&$expanded': {
     transform: 'translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg)',
 },
```

There is no access to this nested class via [component's API](https://material-ui.com/api/expansion-panel-summary/#css), and my need is to override it.
I have tried to do this with jss-nested plugin [as described here](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes) and override with `classes` prop:

```
expandIcon: {
    "&$expanded": {
        transform: "translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg)"
    }
}

<ExpansionPanelSummary
     expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
     classes={{
         expandIcon: classes.expandIcon
     }}
 >
```

But it not works, and I got this warning in the console:

```
Warning: [JSS] Could not find the referenced rule expanded in MyExpansionPanel.
```

You can see live codesandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9kk09lmw9?expanddevtools=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FMyExpansionPanel.js).
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `&$` syntax references a rule in the same style sheet, you need to create an expanded rule and pass it into the classes object e.g.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  expandIcon: {
    "&$expanded": {
      transform: "translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg)"
    }
  },
  expanded: {},
});

<ExpansionPanelSummary
  expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
  classes={{
    expandIcon: classes.expandIcon,
    expanded: classes.expanded,
  }}
>
```

Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/x256q3xz44

Answer (score 1):

In order to override CSS style of the icon on expansion, you need to add classes to both the `ExpansionPanelSummery` and the `ExpandMoreIcon` (this is what you are missing).

```
const styles = theme => ({
  expanded: {
    "& $icon": {
      transform: "translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg)"
    }
  },
  icon: {}
});
<ExpansionPanelSummary
    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon classes={{ root: classes.icon }} />}
    classes={{ expanded: classes.expanded }}
>
```