# What is the JSS syntax for referencing generated class names called?

Tags: jss, css-in-js

Material UI uses JSS at its core and you sometimes need to override styles from their base components.

[Example from `Input`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/Input/Input.js#L65): `'&:hover:not($disabled):before'{ ... }`

I cannot find this syntax mentioned in the [JSS syntax docs](https://cssinjs.org/jss-syntax), so it's hard to discuss with others without a common name. What is it called?

Comment: Which part of that are you asking about? `$disabled`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's the only magic in that rule

Comment: The page you linked to refers to it as *"`$ref` syntax"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe they only use that in the context of a keyframe though. Not confident it's used generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is made possible through [a plugin for nesting](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested).

The plugin itself describes this as "nested selectors", which is also usually the term you will find being used to describe it when searching Stack Overflow.